# Apache can't reach Tomcat: AH00957, AH00959 & AH00896

Tags: apache, tomcat7, httpd.conf, oracle-rest-data-services

I have Tomcat 7.0.105 installed with ords.war deployed in it.
In my browser, I use the URL http://rtp, where rtp is the name of my server as defined in /etc/hosts. This uses port 80 and reaches Apache on the server. There I have a conf file in my /etc/httpd/conf.d folder with these contents:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName rtp

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ords
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/ords
</VirtualHost>
```

But the browser says "Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

And /etc/httpd/logs/error_log shows this:

```
[Tue Aug 18 13:13:55.799950 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8508] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost) failed
[Tue Aug 18 13:13:55.800133 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8508] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
[Tue Aug 18 13:13:55.800220 2020] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 8508] [client 1.2.3.4:50900] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

The Tomcat7 server.xml file is left default like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

What could be the reason for "AJP: attempt to connect to localhost failed". All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tue Aug 18 13:13:55.799950 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 8508] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost) failed

> > You are using localhost in ProxyPass. Is your Apache and tomcat on same server?
> > Check AJP port running or not using `netstat -tunlp | grep 127.0.0.1:8009` command. Also please change ProxyPass configuration.

From:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ords
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/ords
```

To:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Comment: I removed the ords suffix as you suggested, but the end result is the same. The netstat command returned nothing. What does that tell us? And yes, they are on the same server.

Comment: The netstat command retruned nothing means 8009 port is not running on server. Share server.xml file in question.

Comment: I've added the server.xml in the original question

Comment: Could you please uncoment below line and add 127.0.0.0.1. `<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" address="127.0.0.1" port="8009" redirectPort="8443" />`. Restart tomcat and Apache.

Comment: OMG, I didn't notice it was in a comment section. I'd swear the 8009-section wasn't commented in earlier 7.0.x releases. I still have errors in my apache log, but they are different, so I consider this one solved. Thanks a lot for your help @Pandurang !

Answer (score 2):

Update address value to accept connections from hosts.
Remove 1 from address="::1" in AJP connection section.

Below works:
address="::"